# Create a Cache Provider class in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, caching, memcached, autowired

We have memcache on our Symfony 3.4 app:

```
cache:
    app: cache.adapter.memcached
    default_memcached_provider: "%app.memcached.dsn%"
```

However, we've been asked to use several cache servers, so just passing one DSN is no good.

Looking here (https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-memcached-cache-adapter), I see you can create it in code like this:

```
$client = MemcachedAdapter::createConnection(array(
    // format => memcached://[user:pass@][ip|host|socket[:port]][?weight=int]
    // 'weight' ranges from 0 to 100 and it's used to prioritize servers
    'memcached://my.server.com:11211'
    'memcached://rmf:abcdef@localhost'
    'memcached://127.0.0.1?weight=50'
    'memcached://username:the-password@/var/run/memcached.sock'
    'memcached:///var/run/memcached.sock?weight=20'
));
```

However, that isn't autowired.

I believe we need to either make a provider class, or somehow get it to make calls to `addServer($dsn)`, once instantiated. I also saw the following on random posts:

```
memcache:
    class: Memcached
    calls:
        - [ addServer, [ %app.memcached.dsn.1% ]]
        - [ addServer, [ %app.memcached.dsn.2% ]]
```

However it isn't really helping or I have missed something out.

Can anyone help? How do I create this provider class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can copy above code snippet as a service configuration to your services.yaml, which probably roughly looks like this:

```
# app/config/services.yaml

services:
    app.memcached_client:
        class: Memcached
        factory: 'Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\MemcachedAdapter::createConnection'
        arguments: [['memcached://my.server.com:11211', 'memcached://rmf:abcdef@localhost']]

    app.memcached_adapter:
        class: Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\MemcachedAdapter
        arguments:
            - '@app.memcached_client'
```

Then in your configuration you should be able to reference the adapter using the client created by the factory, e.g. something like:

```
# app/config/config.yaml

framework:
    cache:
        app: app.memcached_adapter
```

You might also be able to overwrite the default alias `cache.adapter.memcached` instead of having your own adapter.

Your approach using `Memcached::addServer` might work as well, but just like with `MemcachedAdapter::createConnection` this will return the Client, which needs to be passed to the cache adapter. That's why there is a second service `app.memcached_adapter`, which is used in the cache configuration.

Please be aware that I have not tested this, so this is rather a rough outline than a fully working solution,

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll give this a try!!

Comment: I just fixed a typo in the sevice config. Upon re-reading it looked weird. See https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html

Comment: thanks a lot, i'll tweak it in the morning and hopefully have it up and running by our morning standup! :-D

Comment: That worked, thanks so much! I just had to add extra `[]`'s around the two hosts, arguments are an array, so it thought the second host was the second argument!

Comment: I spoke too soon! :-( I was able to clear cache in the terminal without exceptions etc, but when I loaded the site I got the following : `Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\MemcachedAdapter::__construct() must be an instance of Memcached, string given`, and upon looking in the generated code I saw this `return $this->services['cache.app'] = new \Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\TraceableAdapter(new \Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\MemcachedAdapter('kRTmoLLARw'));` I have no idea why there is a string instead of our client!

Comment: Can you maybe open a new question with the error and your service/cache config? I can't come up with an idea why that might happen.

Comment: sure, I'll do that just now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53086855/symfony-memcachedadapter-construct-must-be-an-instance-of-memcached-stri

Answer (score 1):

For one of my projects running Symfony 3.4 the configuration was simpler:

Create a service that will be used as a client:

```
app.memcached_client:
    class: Memcached
    factory: ['AppBundle\Services\Memcached', 'createConnection']
    arguments: ['memcached://%memcache_ip%:%memcache_port%']
```

The `AppBundle\Services\Memcached` can have all the custom logic I need like so:

```
class Memcached
{
    public static function createConnection($dns)
    {
        $options = [
            'persistent_id' => 'some id'
        ];

        // Some more custom logic. Maybe adding some custom options
        // For example for AWS Elasticache

        if (defined('Memcached::OPT_CLIENT_MODE') && defined('Memcached::DYNAMIC_CLIENT_MODE')) {
            $options['CLIENT_MODE'] = \Memcached::DYNAMIC_CLIENT_MODE;
        }

        return \Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\MemcachedAdapter::createConnection($dns, $options);
    }
}
```

And then I used that service in my config.yml:

```
framework:
    cache:
        default_memcached_provider: app.memcached_client
```