# Symfony - MemcachedAdapter::__construct() must be an instance of Memcached, string given

Tags: php, symfony, caching, memcached, autowired

This is rather bizarre. I have set up caching with Memcached as follows:

> framework.yaml

```
framework:
    cache:
        app: app.memcached_adapter
```

> services.yaml

```
app.memcached_client:
    class: Memcached
    factory: 'Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\MemcachedAdapter::createConnection'
    arguments: [['%app.memcached.dsn.1%', '%app.memcached.dsn.2%']]
    public: true

app.memcached_adapter:
    class: Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\MemcachedAdapter
    arguments:
        - '@app.memcached_client'
    public: true
```

I am able to clear cache in the terminal without any errors, but when I load my site, I get the following:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\MemcachedAdapter::__construct() 
must be an instance of Memcached, string given, called in 
/users/me/project/please-dont-mention-the-company/sports/var/cache/lcl/ContainerXqbuh45/srcLclDebugProjectContainer.php 
on line 1029
```

Upon looking in said generated container class, I found this:

```
/**
 * Gets the public 'cache.app' shared service.
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\TraceableAdapter
 */
protected function getCache_AppService()
{
    return $this->services['cache.app'] = new \Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\TraceableAdapter(new \Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\MemcachedAdapter('kRTmoLLARw'));
}
```

I have no idea how it generated with that string as the argument, it should be the memcached client!

Any ideas? Anything I can check without having to debug the container class generation?

Comment: Your Memcached class really has no namespace at all?  Admittedly the error message does not match up.

Comment: Why would it? It's the PHP Memcached class

Comment: Did you find why are you getting this? I have this problem too

Comment: Hi boyd, not sure, I'm on a different contract now so didn't get to see that issue being resolved. maybe worth adding an issue on github? https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues

Comment: @boyd are you running PHP 5.5? Apparently there's a bug with Memcached on that version, look here https://travis-ci.org/symfony/symfony/builds/181224206

Comment: @delboy1978uk I 'm on PHP 7.2.9

Comment: I have the same error as you guys. Any solutions for it would be very nice

Answer (score 0):

have you tried it to get the CacheAdapter from the Service-Container instead of creating a new Instance here:

`return $this->services['cache.app'] = new \Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\TraceableAdapter(
new \Symfony\Component\Cache\Adapter\MemcachedAdapter('kRTmoLLARw') // new instance?
);`

Comment: That *is* the container service. I'm showing you the generated code that sets up the container service in the first place.